# Poincare-Euler characteristic and sum of two divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, sheaf-theory, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a regular projective algebraic surface over a field $k$. Let $D$ be a divisor on $X$ and suppose that $Y$ is a *prime* irreducible divisor on $X$ (i.e. $Y$ is an irreducible curve in $X$).

> Is there any relationship  between  $\chi_k(\mathcal O_X(D))$ and
>   $\chi_k(\mathcal O_X(D-Y))$?

Here with $\chi_k$ I denote the Euler-Poincare characteristic of a sheaf.

Comment: You do have $\chi(D)=\chi(D-Y)+\chi(D|Y)$. Are you expecting something more?

Comment: Hoow do you prove that formula?

Comment: You have an exact sequence, $0\to D-Y\to D\to D|Y\to 0$, tensoring the exact sequence $0\to O(-Y)\to O_X\to O_Y\to 0$ by $O_X(D)$. Euler characteristic is additive.